# How to send videos to process on the server side

Tags: php, python, server, server-side, video-processing

I want to ask a few questions about sending a video file to be process on the server side.
So right now I have a php-based web app where I used to upload my video into the server that hosted my web app, 
and I have a python files where I use to process the video (process such as cutting a portion of video,
removing the green screen) which took time to process on my computer.

What I have done right now:

Web app (to upload video from mobile to server) -> download file from server to my computer 
-> manually process videos

What I planned:

Web app (to upload video to server and process those video automatically from the server) -> 
notifying user when process are done (so user doesn't need to be on the app waiting for the process) 
-> download processed video from the web app

As I described above, I want the video process to be done on the server automatically which will 
take less time to process the video. So, how can I do this based on what I've described? Or if there
are any better way to make the process take less time and automatically on the app, I would appreciate that.
Another things is that, based on what I've planned, are there anything that I have to look out? (I am very
new to php and doing server things)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of a queue system. When a user uploads a video you add a task into that queue (store it in the database).

Now make a cron job that processes the tasks in the queue. It takes the task from the database, finds the video and executes the python scripts. When a task is finished it notify the applicable user (through mail I guess).

Since you are new to server things: here is a link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Frameworks like Symfony have nice solutions for your purpose https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html

Comment: Thank for replying me, I will look into the source you gave.

Comment: So without the plan I mentioned(using cron job to notify blah blah), how can I send the video to process on server. I don't get the idea (what should be change in my python code to make it fit with the server-side process, do I have to copy those python file to the server).

Comment: You have to run the python script on the server by executing the python script with a cron job where you give the file as an argument for example.

Comment: Can ask you some silly question? How/what tool that should be use to the python script on the server. Another thing is that my python code right now read the input from the name (like I have to compile and run the file everytime and if I need to change the video, I have to rewrite the code to that particular video/audio name). Do I have to rewrite the code to make it executable on the terminal?